# Redirecting locally originated traffic with DNAT in OUTPUT chain not working as expected

Tags: linux, routing, container, network-namespaces, netfilter

I am having a dumb, and I am hoping you lovely people can jumpstart my brain.

I am running a service in a local network namespace. The namespace looks like this:

```
# ip -n ns1 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ns1-int@if5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6e:35:ab:46:78:71 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.255.11/24 scope global ns1-int
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6c35:abff:fe46:7871/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The namespace routing table looks like:

```
$ ip -n ns1 route
default via 192.168.255.1 dev ns1-int
192.168.255.0/24 dev ns1-int proto kernel scope link src 192.168.255.11
```

Where interface `ns1-int` is one end of a `veth` pair which is connected to `br0` on the host. 192.168.255.1 is the address of `br0`:

```
# ip addr show br0
4: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ce:10:da:46:71:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.255.1/24 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::cc10:daff:fe46:71fb/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
# ip addr show master br0
5: ns1-ext@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d6:69:bd:06:9c:fa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns ns1
    inet6 fe80::d469:bdff:fe06:9cfa/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I'm running a [simple web service](https://github.com/traefik/whoami) on port 80; I can access it from the host using the namespace address:

```
# curl 192.168.255.11
Hostname: node1
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: ::1
IP: 192.168.255.11
IP: fe80::6c35:abff:fe46:7871
RemoteAddr: 192.168.255.1:58396
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.255.11
User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
Accept: */*
```

I would like to expose this service on host port 8080, both for remotely originating traffic **and** for locally originating traffic.

Remote traffic is no problem:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.255.11:80
```

This works just fine; from another host on the network I can now access the same web endpoint on port 8080:

```
anotherhost$ curl 192.168.121.67:8080
Hostname: node1
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: ::1
IP: 192.168.255.11
IP: fe80::6c35:abff:fe46:7871
RemoteAddr: 192.168.121.1:47888
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.121.67:8080
User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
Accept: */*
```

I would also like to be able to access the service locally on port 8080 using e.g. `curl localhost:8080`. In theory, to redirect locally generated traffic we just need a rule in the `OUTPUT` chain:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.255.11:80
```

At this point the complete netfile configuration looks like:

```
# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.9 on Sun Jun 11 00:47:49 2023
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [751:53502]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [10:937]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [433:43385]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jun 11 00:47:49 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.9 on Sun Jun 11 00:47:49 2023
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [21:1580]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [22:1640]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.255.11:80
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.255.11:80
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jun 11 00:47:49 2023
```

Attempts to access `localhost:8080` simply get stuck:

```
$ curl --connect-timeout 60 localhost:8080
curl: (28) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 60001 ms: Timeout was reached
```

The `OUTPUT` rule is definitely matching; I can see the hit counter incrementing as a I run that `curl` command. I feel like I'm missing something simple. What could it be?

Answer (score 2):

For that `DNAT` rule in the `OUTPUT` chain to work correctly, it looks like we need two things.

1. We need to set the appropriate `route_localnet` sysctl:

   ```
   sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.br0.route_localnet
   ```

   With just that change, we'll see the following traffic showing up inside the namespace:

   ```
   03:23:02.984603 ns1-int In  IP 127.0.0.1.39656 > 192.168.255.11.80: Flags [S], seq 409674911, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 2257175047 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
   ```

   That's problematic because the source address (`127.0.0.1`) is useless, so...
2. We need a `MASQUERADE` rule for traffic **from** `localhost` **to** the namespace:

   ```
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 127.0.0.1/32 -d 192.168.255.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
   ```

With these two rules in place, things work as expected:

```
# curl localhost:8080
Hostname: node1
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: ::1
IP: 192.168.255.11
IP: fe80::8054:55ff:fef7:3e76
RemoteAddr: 192.168.255.1:36676
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
Accept: */*
```

And inside the namespace, we see that the incoming packets now look like:

```
03:26:38.660882 ns1-int In  IP 192.168.255.1.38500 > 192.168.255.11.80: Flags [S], seq 1141073629, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 2257390724 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```